# Best Large Language Model for abstractive Summarization

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, summarization, large-language-model

Browsing through Huggingfaces I am not able to find any abstractive summarization model for longer texts like newsarticle, with a size of around 5000 characters.

I compared different models but none of them really worked. Mostly they are restricted to around 512 input characters which creates a need for splitting, which then made results even worse.

Given the fact that I want to run the models locally, what is the proper way of addressing my problem?

- Fine-tuning
- did I oversee a model
- ...